# Build errors in Keychain.swift when compiling in XCode, iOS development

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods

Xcode version is 7.3.1
OSX 10.11.6

This link accurately describes the issues I'm having

https://github.com/marketplacer/keychain-swift/issues/37

[Errors I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIV9X.jpg) make it clear that my system just isn't recognizing the Keychain.Swift file.

The above link suggests the file is in Swift 3.0, and I double checked that I am running Swift 2.2.

So I tried to install the older version of Keychain.Swift via cocoapods and it seems to update in my system, but I'm still experiencing the same build errors.

I placed "pod 'KeychainSwift', '~> 3.0'" inside the pod file in Xcode and ran "install pod" from terminal inside the project directory.

I tried shutting down Xcode and reopening, I tried running Product-> clean, but nothing seems to work.

The project is a work file that was pulled from github and seems to work on the original authors environment, but I have yet to successfully get my environment to work.

I appreciate any advice and suggestions. I am new to swift, cocoapods, and iOS development.

Comment: Which xcode version are you using?

Comment: Knew I was forgetting something! Version 7.3.1. I'll edit my post, thanks.

Comment: Please check following answer it should work

Answer (score 0):

As i can see the current version of `Keychain.Swift` you are using is in `Swift 3.0`

> It is giving you error of `Date` class which is introduced in `Swift
>   3.0`
>   [Date Class Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/date) Unfortunately Which is supported in ios 10+

Please follow the below steps to remove the previous version and switch to older version:

1. Remove this line `"pod 'KeychainSwift', '~> 3.0'"` from your pod and run `install pod` this will remove the current `KeychainSwift` pod.
2. Now add this line `pod 'KeychainSwift', git: "https://github.com/marketplacer/keychain-swift.git", branch: "swift_2_3"` [Reference taken form this link](https://github.com/marketplacer/keychain-swift/wiki/Legacy-Swift-versions) this will install `Swift 2.3` version of the file.

Enjoy Coading.

Comment: I've removed and added as you've suggested and still no luck. I've restarted Xcode and my Mac.
There does appear to be an update for Xcode so I'll give that a try and report back.

Thanks for the support you've provided so far!

Comment: are you still facing the same issue?

Comment: and also can you upload your current .swift file which is installed after above steps.

Comment: I've narrowed it down to when I add "pod 'KeychainAccess'" into my podfile. When I comment it out the build errors associated with "keychain.swift" go away, but then I can no longer "import KeychainAccess" and use that library. So I'm still facing the same issue. You would like me to upload the keychain.swift file?

Comment: Adding "pod KeychainAccess" adds a file called "Keychain.swift". When I tried to install the correct version via the directions in your answer, it creates a file called "keychainswift.swift". I just end up with two separate files in two separate folders with slightly different names. Could this be the problem?

Comment: You're advice was dead on! We just needed the right library (see answer posted)! I'm just hopping on this project and I'm not familiar with the libraries, or I would have realized this sooner! Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there are multiple libraries for utilizing the keychain. There is one called KeychainAccess and another one called Keychain-swift. One utilizes "import KeychainAccess" and the other "import KeychainSwift". I simply had the version for swift 3.0 when I'm using 2.2 (which we knew from the start, but still couldn't get it to work). The advice given by Harshal Bhavsar is accurate, but only if you are using "KeychainSwift". Otherwise, you want to roll back to an older version of "KeychainAccess" found here https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/KeychainAccess/releases.